# Get VW/VH position from onclick event in JS

Tags: javascript, css, dom, addeventlistener, viewport-units

This code will give me the x and y value of the click in pixels:

```js
document.getElementById("game").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   console.log(event.clientX, event.clientY);
});
```

But how do I get the X and Y values comparitive to VH (Viewport Height) and VW (Viewport Width) (I want to get the value like how in CSS you can set an element to be 20vh [20% of viewport height] etc etc)

Comment: You can not get these values in CSS. You can only get them through JavaScript.

Comment: @ArslanAkram I added better context. This is not what I mean't.

Comment: Thanks for the context. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to get the Viewport Width (vw) by using `window.innerWidth` and Viewport Height (vh) by using `window.innerHeight`.

Then, divide the `event.clientX` by `vw` and multiply by `100` to get value in percentages. Same logic to get Y co-ordinates, i.e. divide the `event.clientY` by `vh` and multiply by `100` to get value in percentages.

See my demo below: (Click on Game to get the co-ordinates)

```js
let gameEl = document.getElementById("game"),
  eCXinVWEl = document.getElementById("eCXinVW"),
  eCYinVHEl = document.getElementById("eCYinVH");

gameEl.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let vw = window.innerWidth,
    vh = window.innerHeight,
    eCXinVW = event.clientX / vw * 100, // Multiplying by 100 to get percentage 
    eCYinVH = event.clientY / vh * 100; // Multiplying by 100 to get percentage 

  console.log(eCXinVW, eCYinVH);

  eCXinVWEl.innerHTML = eCXinVW;
  eCYinVHEl.innerHTML = eCYinVH;
});
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 50px;
}

#game {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <h6>Event co-ordinates X by viewport width: <span id="eCXinVW">0</span>%</h6>
      <h6>Event co-ordinates Y by viewport height: <span id="eCYinVH">0</span>%</h6>

      <div id="game">Game</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this ?

You just need to get the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` from the `window` element than compute the percentage with a *cross product*

```
(elementX * 100) / viewport width
(elementY * 100) / viewport heght
```

```js
document.getElementById("game")
  .addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const debug = document.getElementById('debug');
    const clickX = event.clientX;
    const clickY = event.clientY;
      
    const vh = window.innerHeight;
    const vw = window.innerWidth;
  
    const ratioX = (clickX * 100) / vw;
    const ratioY = (clickY * 100) / vh;
  
    debug.innerHTML = '';
    debug.append(`X:${clickX}  Y:${clickY}`);
    debug.append("\n");
    debug.append(`%X:${ratioX} %Y:${ratioY}`);

  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lemon;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#game {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 29.7vw;
  height: 21vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6), 0px 0px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

```html
<div id=game></div>

<pre id=debug>
  X:   Y:
  %X: %Y: 
</pre>
```